# nvm proxy settings configuration file

Tags: node.js, nvm

Under Linux, I use `$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy` which works well for `node` and `npm` but `nvm` doesn't use them.

In which configuration file should I write the proxy settings?

> uname -a: Linux Breizh-Atao 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 27, accepted):

NVM uses curl, so modifying the file **~/.curlrc** file (or create it if it does not exist)

```
proxy = <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer of @Nahuel, the file `~/.curlrc` should also contain a line with `insecure`.

```
# cat ~/.curlrc
proxy = http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
insecure
```