# Why are directories missing on nodejs ubuntu install using n?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I've been around the houses with this and over multiple resources. My issue is basically the install of nodejs 10.17.0. I'm committed to using npm due to proxy bypasses.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm

nodejs -v gives v4.2.6

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 10.17.0

cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0/lib': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0/bin': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0/include': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0/share': No such file or directory
installed : v10.17.0 (with npm 6.11.3)

nodejs -v gives v4.2.6
```

Comment: If the only thing that prevents you from using NVM is a proxy, maybe this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244572/nvm-proxy-settings-configuration-file

Comment: Just removed the /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0 and getting different behavior, waiting for result.

Comment: Removal of the folder worked.

Comment: Still got blocked using n to install but wget was fine probably due to headers and an IPS in line. So I used wget to put the tarball in usr/local and ran n install again and it used the pre-download tar ball successfully.